# Problems when trying to install the prisma dependency with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, prisma

I am trying to set up a project with next.js, and when I install the prisma dependency with the command `npm i -D prisma` I get the following error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! prisma@4.8.1 preinstall: `node scripts/preinstall-entry.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the prisma@4.8.1 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Checking the logs I see the following capture
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
For whatever reason, when I try to run the script `prisma@4.8.1 preinstall: node scripts/preinstall-entry.js` I get those terminal errors and the installation is interrupted.

Checking and informing myself, https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/system-requirements, I read about checking the node version, but they ask for a minimum version of `14.17.X` or higher and I have version `14.16.0`, on the other hand, npm completely updated.

If I update node, can I have compatibility problems with other projects I have?
I have also tried to delete the node_modules folder, package-lock, do `npm clean cache --force`, and re-run npm install with everything in my package.json, but the error persists....
If you can think of anything I would appreciate it

Best regards!

Comment: If the docs say that Node 14.17.X is required then I would not expect it to work with 14.16.0. The preinstall script [specifically checks for the required Node version](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/blob/61c00c005316360b8287c427204dc6e4338e8fa9/packages/cli/scripts/preinstall.js#L47).

Comment: Looks like its the version issue. To confirm you can try installing it in a new project as well and this shall fail. 

I checked with 14.17.0 and it works. You can try checking safely by installing 14.17.0 node version using nvm and check if it works on a new project. nvm allows you install multiple node versions and to switch node versions in different projects.

If this works delete the node_modules, package-lock.json in your existing project and install the dependencies using 14.17.0. I don't think this would cause any issues in your project as its a minor version upgrade

Comment: @subodhkalika I will try to do that, then I have to uninstall my node, and install nvm for windows in my case right?
This will not give me problems with other projects? It is a little bit the fear that I have

Comment: @ChrisYungmann thanks for your comment, i will try to do upgrade

Comment: it works, after updating the node version, everything is in order, thank you very much for your comments.